# Canvas remove white Pixels in Images

Tags: javascript, css, image, canvas, pixel

I have been looking at [canvas ImageData remove white pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755314/canvas-imagedata-remove-white-pixels) to get ride of white pixels in my images but it doesn't work as it doesn't recognise putImageData(). Is there a way to create a method to get rid of white pixels by passing an image in and returning the image back again. I have multiple images already on the canvas but all have white backgrounds.

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't recognise putImageData()"?

Comment: @Pointy It is mentioned at the bottom of the example I linked to but it never works for me

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get errors in the developer console?

Comment: @pointy yes states that it is not a function

Comment: OK well you'll have to post the code you're trying to use in order for anyone to help.

Comment: Are you getting a warning about a Security Error if you look in the Console?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1: Is the putImageData definitely being called from ctx?

2: is the first argument in putImageData, "imageData"?

3: This is the most important one. Is the image being called from another domain? If so, you need to download the image to your domain by right clicking the image, clicking "save image as...", and then posting it to your directory. Hope this helps,

Awesomeness01